# Can someone explain how the frequency of a string relates to the tension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, string, continuum-mechanics

and come to the conclusion that the The fundamental frequency of a vibrating string is directly proportional to the square root of the tension using equations please. This is for a lab i'm doing on guitar strings

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration

Comment: dimensional analysis

Comment: @MilanPin Using standing waves.

Answer (score -1):

The wave speed can be related to the tension and the mass per unit length of the string by the following equation:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$

Here, $T$ is the tension, $\mu$ the mass per unit length and $v$ the speed of waves on the string. For a derivation of this equation refer to [this](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/16-3-wave-speed-on-a-stretched-string/) or to any first year Physics textbook (e.g. Halliday & Resnick).

In the fundamental vibrational mode of the string, the two 
the ends are half a wavelength apart. In the $n$th harmonic, the length $l$ of the string is $\frac{n \lambda}{2}$. Thus, the wavelength $\lambda$ of the string is $\frac{2l}{n}$. Apply the wave equation:

$$ v = nf_{1} \frac{2l}{n} \implies \sqrt\frac{T}{\mu} = 2lf_{1} \implies f_{1} = \frac{1}{2l}\sqrt\frac{T}{\mu}$$

[image: Here's an image to explain what's going on]